# Continuous Mapping Theorem

Tags: uniform-convergence

I am trying to investigate conditions for the functions random variables relating to convergence.

Suppose $X_n$ and $X$ are $1$-dimensional random variables and suppose that $X_n$ converges to $X$ in probability.  Under what conditions on the function $f$, we have $f(X_n)$ converges to $f(X)$.

Comment: Hint: $X_n\to X$ in probability if and only if for every subsequence $X_{n_k}$ there exists a subsequence $X_{n_{k_l}}$ which converges to $X$ almost surely.